# Audio cuts out on webpages

Tags: ios, google-chrome, safari, soundjs

I am working on a website which gives users the option to have the pages read aloud to them.

I am using SoundJS (https://www.createjs.com/soundjs) to load in an OGG, MP3, and WAV version of a narration file, and then play it as soon as it finishes loading. Here is the code:

```
var narration = {
    path: '../assets/sounds/',
        manifest: [
            {
                id: 'narration',
                src: {
                    mp3: 'narration.mp3',
                    ogg: 'narration.ogg',
                    wav: 'narration.wav'
                }
            }
        ]
    };

createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ['mp3', 'wav'];
createjs.Sound.registerSounds(narration);
createjs.Sound.addEventListener('fileload', function(){
    createjs.Sound.play('narration');
});
```

On the iPhone X and iPad, in Safari and Chrome, the audio file starts playing, but then cuts out before it finishes. The audio files on the site range from 7 to over 30 seconds, and the audio always cuts out a few seconds before the end. For instance, in Chrome, a 10 second clip stops playing after 8 seconds, and a 31 second clip stops playing after 29. In Safari, the same 10 second clip stops after 7 seconds, and the same 31 second clip stops after 22.

On all non-iOS devices we've tested, in many different browsers, this issue has never occurred.

**What is the reason behind this, and what can I do to ensure the audio plays all the way through?**

Comment: Have got any solution to this issue? I'm also facing similar issue, where issue occurs in iOS 13.

Comment: Can you try setting `duration` manually and see if it plays the clip properly?

Comment: @CodingSomething I believe the duration attribute on a SoundJS object is read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there is no solution found for this issue, we're considering it a bug with iOS mobile devices, and not something we can control.

As a workaround, we've implemented a button on each page that the user must click before the audio plays. The button runs `createjs.Sound.play('narration')`, rather than it being triggered through the `fileload` event listener. For some reason, registering a click on each page *before* attempting to play audio allows it to play all the way through, reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the HTML5 audio element? Simply add it as an element that appears over the Canvas. I added an audio element, "", and it seems to work well in my iPad